# Invalid Scopes: publish_stream, offline_access while login using facebook api with joomla 3x btsocialconnect component

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, joomla, authentication

i have used btsocialconnect in joomla 3. when i login with facebook login, it shows the following error.

> Invalid Scopes: publish_stream, offline_access. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

how can i remove publish_stream, offline_access?

Comment: why not just stop asking for those in the authorization process?

Comment: I would guess you need to update btsocialconnect or ask them to fix it

Comment: I couldn't found solution. Then I have replaced the social login section of btsocialconnect component with Slogin component.

Comment: Slogin component have more features than btsocialconnect. Better use Slogin in joomla. It have account merge options for existing mail ids. It will be useful and convenient.